# What is C# Equivalent to C++ STL fill method

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, fill, equivalent

In C++, we can set a range of values of an array(and other similar containers) using fill.

For example,

```
fill(number, number+n,10);
```

The above code will set the first n values of the array number with the value 10.

What is the closest C# equivalent to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no equivalent method but there are many ways to write similar code

Methods from the Linq-to-Objects classes can create sequences that you can use to initialize lists but this is very different from how things in C++ actually occur.

```
new List<char>(Enumerable.Repeat('A', 10));
new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
```

C++ can accomplish these things more generally thanks to how C++ templates work, and while simple type constraints in C# help, they do not offer the same flexibility.

Comment: Why not use `ToList` on the result of `Repeat`, and thus avoid needing to explicitly specify the list type?

Comment: @Richard I don't see why not, there are many ways to construct lists, I really like type inference but used the constructors in this example.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure one exists, but you can code your own easily:

```
void Fill<T>(T[] array, int start, int count, T value)
{
  for (int i = start, j = 0; j < count; i++, j++)
    array[i] = value;
}
```

Obviously missing parameter checking, but you get the drill.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent, but you can do it in two steps. First use `Enumerable.Repeat` to create an array with the same value in each element. Then copy that over the destination array:

```
var t = Enumerable.Repeat(value, count).ToArray();
Array.Copy(t, 0, dest, destStartIndex, count);
```

For other destination containers there is a lack of an equivalent to `Array.Copy`, but it is easy to add these as destinations, eg:

```
static void Overwrite<T>(this List<T> dest, IEnumerable<T> source, int destOffset) {
  int pos = destOffset;
  foreach (var val in source) {
    // Could treat this as an error, or have explicit count
    if (pos = dest.Length) { return; }

    dest[pos++] = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Should probably just make a `Fill` extension method if that's what you need. This is rather expensive (even if it's a more general solution to the problem). Also, if we change the parameter `List<T> dest` to `IList<T> dest` it should work on arrays as well as lists.